# Fix error `Module build failed: Error: Cannot find module 'ajv'`

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, vue-cli

I'm getting the error `Module build failed: Error: Cannot find module 'ajv'` when trying to run `vue-cli-service serve --mode dev` in my application.

`ajv` is being installed as a dependency of other packages, it's not a direct dependency in my `package.json`. I'm using versions node: `v14.17.6` and npm : `6.14.15`

`npm install` runs perfectly, the error only appears when running `vue-cli-service serve --mode dev`

The full error trace is as follows:

```
ERROR in ./src/main.ts
Module build failed: Error: Cannot find module 'ajv'
Require stack:
- /Users/<user>/node_modules/schema-utils/dist/validate.js
- /Users/<user>/node_modules/schema-utils/dist/index.js
- /Users/<user>/node_modules/cache-loader/dist/index.js
- /Users/<user>/node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js
- /Users/<user>/<project>/node_modules/webpack/lib/ProgressPlugin.js
- /Users/<user><project>/node_modules/progress-webpack-plugin/index.js
- /Users/<user><project>/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/commands/serve.js
- /Users/<user>/<project>//node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/Service.js
- /Users/<user>/<project>/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/bin/vue-cli-service.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:889:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:745:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:961:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:92:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/<user>/node_modules/schema-utils/dist/validate.js:15:13)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:961:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:92:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/<user>/node_modules/schema-utils/dist/index.js:3:18)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:12)


webpack compiled with 1 error
No issues found.
```

Any idea what could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/5469

- Delete node_modules in the project
- npm cache verify
- npm install